# Do Custom Elements require a dash in their name?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component, x-tag

Is it possible to name your own custom elements `<date>`, `<person>`, `<city>` or others without the use of a dash? Can use define elements without them?

Answer (score 94):

All browsers support a finite list of HTML elements which are considered as "known". Elements which are unknown (e.g `<city>`, `<person>`) do not generally throw errors with the HTML parser in modern browsers and instead inherit from `HTMLUnknownElement`. In older versions of IE however, such elements would be inserted into the DOM as an empty node without any children (1).

The [Custom Elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html) specification [requires](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name) that all custom elements contain a hyphen (`-`) in the name. So rather than `<person>`, you would use `<my-person>` or `<x-person>`. These are valid names, whilst `<person`> is considered an unknown element.

The dash effectively allows the HTML parser to tell the difference between true custom elements and regular elements. It also allows us to enable a level of future capability when standards groups add new tags to HTML.

You can use any hyphen-separated name with the exception of:

- `annotation-xml`
- `color-profile`
- `font-face`
- `font-face-src`
- `font-face-uri`
- `font-face-format`
- `font-face-name`
- `missing-glyph`

To the best of my knowledge, these names are reserved names from SVG, MathML and other specs. For example, here's more [info](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#FontFaceElement) on the `<font-face>` element.

*(1) This gave rise to the hack where developers would create a dummy HTML5 tag in IE (e.g `<article>`) using JavaScript so that they could then style it per any normal element with CSS.*

Comment: Would you be able to expand or link to why the `annotation-xml`/etc can't be used?

Comment: Sure! I've added a brief note. Basically, I believe they're reserved names for elements used or mentioned in other specs that you would want to avoid colliding with.

Comment: So in other words, you cannot overspecify a tag?

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is requirement for this elements to have lowercase names as well

Comment: Does "must contain a hyphen" mean that a custom element can start with a hyphen? Anyone know?

Comment: I wish I knew this before I spent 2 hours beating my head against a wall trying to get polymer to work.  This should be plastered all over the front page of any docs even closely related to custom elements.  Chrome/FF/Safari throw no errors, and even show the element in the DOM tree, but refuse to render the inner html.  Horrible behavior.

Comment: Can a custom element name contain two dashes, e.g. my-custom-element?

Comment: @addyo can you clarify what you said about "In older versions of IE however, such elements [have problems]" — What about custom elements (containing dashes), do they also suffer from the same problems in old IE?

Comment: Keep in mind that even though you're not supposed to create new elements without a dash in the name, it still works perfectly fine in all modern browsers if you do.

Comment: @MatthewDean A custom element CANNOT start with a hyphen... but it can end with a hyphen! So this is not allowed: `<-comp></-comp>`, but this is allowed: `<comp-></comp->`

Comment: @yglodt Yes, a custom element CAN contain multiple dashes.

Comment: @Gavin As far as I am aware, while you can still use tags without a dash and style them, they will always be of type `HTMLUnknownElement`. In other words, you cannot define a class that extends an HTMLElement and then call `customElements.define('myelem', MyElem);` to register it as a custom element without an error or without adding a dash to the name.