# What tag should be used for a logo element if the logo is text?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have read that an `<h1>` tag [is inappropriate for a logo](http://www.fastcompany.com/3016894/should-your-tag-be-your-logo). But if your logo is plain text, what should you use? I feel like `<p>` and `<span>` are also unsuitable. Here's a sample:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <a id="logo" href=".">
      <span>Company Name</span>
    </a>
    <a id="linkOne" href="#thingOne">
      <img src="…">
    </a>
    <a id="linkTwo" href="#thingTwo">
      <img src="…">
    </a>
    <a id="linkThree" href="#thingThree">
      <img src="…">
    </a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your markup example, you seem to ask about a link in the `nav` element. If that’s the case, you should not use a heading element for it, because the heading element would label the `nav` section (that’s probably not what you want to convey; if you would have a heading in `nav`, it should probably be something like "Navigation").

In that case, you wouldn’t need a special element at all, just list the links in `nav` (ideally within a `ul`):

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="logo" href="." rel="home">Company Name</a></li>
      <li><a id="linkOne" href="#thingOne"><img src="…" alt="…"></a></li>
      <li><a id="linkTwo" href="#thingTwo"><img src="…" alt="…"></a></li>
      <li><a id="linkThree" href="#thingThree"><img src="…" alt="…"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

However, if you talk about the site name that gets (typically) shown in the site-wide banner/header on each page, using a `h1` makes sense, because it represents the site, in which scope all of the page’s sections should be (e.g., the site-wide navigation), and it gives the document outline a top-level label (which would be unspecified otherwise). In that case it must not be part of the `nav`; its nearest section should be the `body` sectioning root.

Semantically, it makes no difference if the site name/logo is shown as image or as text. In case of an image, the `alt` attribute provides equivalent content as text.

So for a site logo you might have:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1><a href="/" rel="home"><img src="…" alt="ACME Inc."></a></h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

And for a site name you might have:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1><a href="/" rel="home">ACME Inc.</a></h1>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 18):

There is no "semantic" way (i.e. syntax) to markup a logo in HTML, so on a fundamental level there is no right or wrong way. That said, I would not use a `<h1>` for a logo, since the heading-tags should structure your HTML.

I usually use a simple `<div>` or `<a>` with the logo as a background image because I think that's the nicest way to hide it from screen readers. Frankly I don't see much value of putting the logo as an `<img>` in a `<section>` since a section should encompass a thematic grouping of content.

In your case, I'd format your `<a>` as `inline-block` and set the logo as a background image.

Comment: The logo is plain text, not an image.

Comment: Then why not just use an <a>-tag?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Simple, right? I was just probing at whether it was the best semantic choice. Perhaps it was a silly question.

Comment: I am done waiting for w3c for 15+ years. I am using `<brand>` as default branding tag. `<img>`, `<a>` and `<span>` inside brand to support feasability.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the tag would be mostly up to you.

I do not see why it shouldn't be h1, given that is plain text.

But analysing your case, this is what I would do.

Option 1. Use h1 and determine it as the tag to be used to display the logo. Never again it should be used in the dom.

Option 2. Create a new tag for the logo, such as . These are called "Custom elements". It should go something like this:

```
var logo = document.registerElement('com-logo', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

Then you would have to format the logo with CSS.

Read [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) to learn a little bit more about the custom elements! :)

Comment: I'm not sure about making my own element. I'm tempted to just leave it in the a tag directly. But as for where I read that about the h1 tag: http://www.fastcompany.com/3016894/should-your-tag-be-your-logo

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the currently accepted answer, we should ideally not use the `H1` to wrap your brand name, as:

- I understand that the best and proper use of `H1` is to give a top level heading to a **webpage/document**, not the *site itself* (ie, having all documents titled as the site name just doesn't make sense in this context), and
- Using multiple `H1s` is generally considered bad practice (which would be necessary if you want to title your documents/pages using `H1` as you should).

After pondering this I believe the best answer is to therefore **express the brand name by including schema.org microdata**, and then use whatever tag you feel is reasonable for you.

Eg you can see the example taken from down near the bottom of https://schema.org/LocalBusiness:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Restaurant">
  <span itemprop="name">GreatFood</span>
```

Hope that helps answer this question more definitively!

Answer (score 0):

There's no really a correct answer for this as there had been no official semantic element for sites' logos while for example, we have `<figure>` for images, `<blockquote>` && `<q>` for quote blocks and quotation marks, and `<main>` is self-explanatory

#### so from a personal point of view:

- `figure > img` if logo is an image
- `div > span` for textual ones

#### now why `div > span`?

- h1 should be used only once on the page (unfortunately I have no official ref) *&&* Search engines will see the logo as the first heading
- bad UI if you make the link for HOME page in the logo as some users are not used to clicking on the site logo if they don't find a HOME link
- `div`s are not helpful for screen readers so they ain bad for SEO in this case unlike say a `<section>` which wouldn't make sense
- not just `span` as a container would help in styling like centering

  last but not least should you put the logo inside the nav or outside: inside
  for the same reason as wrapping `<span>` inside of `<div>`

#### To sum up

1. put the elements holding the logo inside the nav
2. use either

- `figure > img`
- `div > span`

3. make a separate HOME link for better UI

hope I helped:)

Answer (score -4):

Just use `<site-logo>...</site-logo>`. The [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) wont complain [as long as the element contains a dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545621/do-custom-elements-require-a-dash-in-their-name/22545622#22545622).