# Typescript complains Property does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' when using React.createClass?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using typescript to write redux application.

```
var item = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>hello world</div>)
  }
});

export default class ItemList extends Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (<item />)
    }
}
```

Then typescript complains this:

```
Property 'item' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

Comment: try <Item /> use this with pascal case. Its case sensitive

Comment: @RM-123 No, it can be `item`. `item` with lowercase is a valid HTML element name. Custom Elements can all be lowercase elements just like the intrinsic ones.

Comment: @trusktr No, it _can't_ be `item`. Custom elements _must_ contain `-` a hyphen. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545621/do-custom-elements-require-a-dash-in-their-name)

Comment: @Qwerty Doh, I knew that. I think I meant that it is valid to write arbitrary element names in the DOM. You can write `<blahblah>` and it will be there. But there's no way to register a `<blahblah>` element.

Comment: @trusktr No, it is **not valid** to write arbitrary element names in lowercase (without the hyphen) even though it will probably compile and work.

Comment: It'd be nice if it were, because it is valid HTML.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Your component must start with a capital letter `I` instead of small letter `i` otherwise TypeScript would yell. Changing `item` to `Item` should fix it:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>hello world</div>)
  }
});

export default class ItemList extends Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (<Item />)
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear to future face-palmers, the trick is the capital letter `I` in `Item`. We're all here having the same lapse in judgement here trying to camelCase a react element. Chances are if you're reading this you're sleep deprived enough to miss that capital letter too.

Comment: Just as reference: this also applies to Functional Components. Function name should be capitalized as well.

Comment: here i am again a month later (face palm)

Answer (score 64):

You can declare your custom element type like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      item: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Just to add in case it's not obvious, if your custom component is named like "my-item" then the syntax is ['my-item']: React.DetailedHTMLProps...

Comment: For Next.js add it to a file filename.d.ts and don't forget to include it in tsconfig.json
  "include": [... "filename.d.ts"],

Answer (score 39):

That is because your `item` component's name does not start with a capital letter, causing Typescript to complain. Replacing `item` with `Item` could solve this problem.

Answer (score 32):

For anyone else stuck on this.

The solutions was to

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Typescript complained

```
Property 'div' does not exist on type 'StyledInterface'.
```

and

```
Property 'div' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

I think the root cause was vscode (me) accidentally editing type definitions in node_modules .

Comment: I concur, vscode does rename the type definition when one use the refactoring feature on a component, e.g. `<button>` → `<a>`

Comment: Said in another way, you pressed F2 on a tag to change it to something else and you literally renamed in in the type definitions. `npm uninstall @types/react` and `npm install --save-dev @types/react` did it for me.

Comment: I guess it can happen that way too, i think i did find/replace

Comment: In addition to downloading a fresh copy of node_modules, you may need to restart VS Code for the errors to go away.

Answer (score 9):

It looked like I had the same problem as in this question, but it was typo :/  But I've decided to share that here since error looked very similar and google led me here.

I had typo in declaration:

```
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinisicElements {
            'about-me': { me: string }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of **IntrinsicElements** I had *IntrinisicElements* (extra 'i' letter after 'Intrin').  The compiler didn't complain that because it is definition of interface, so the name can be of our choice.

And the error was like that:

> Property 'about-me' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Comment: I checked mine as we also have a "`long-string`" kind of prop and it didn't work for me, even after setting it to `any`, but for me any prop on `interface IntrinisicElements {` breaks.

Answer (score 9):

For all those who faced similar error:

```
Property 'div' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

Or any other tag instead of div.
If other solutions didn't help, try adding to `tsconfig.json`:

```
...    
"compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
...
```

Comment: Didn't help in our case.

Comment: this worked for me! i had it set to "node10" previously (the typescript default iirc), but this fixed it

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else who has run into this and the previous answers did not work, this can also happen in a `.tsx` file due to a misconfiguration of your `tsconfig.json` file.

I had the error with:

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
   "jsx": "react-jsx"
}
...
```

And solved it by changing it to just:

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
   "jsx": "react"
}
...
```

Again, the above answers are probably the first thing to check, but if you're getting these errors on standard HTML elements like `div`, `span`, etc and you're using Typescript. Check your tsconfig.json!

Answer (score 7):

Remember: "item" is not valid in TypeScript, you must declare as "Item", UpperCase the first letter!
It is will be like:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>hello world</div>)
  }
});
```

Good day!

Answer (score 4):

This could happen if you just renamed a tag by pressing `F2` on it in VSCode, which could change the typing of the tag.

When the rename happened, some `index.d.ts` file should have opened in a new tab. Check if the tab is still open. The path might be something like `.../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`.

If you find the tab, go into it, then press ctrl-z (cmd-z) to undo your change.

If you don't see the tab, you probably have closed it. Try to use your hotkey to reopen recently closed tabs. If you don't know the hotkey, use command palette `View: Reopen Closed Editor`. Keep doing it until you find the file, then undo your change. (VSCode remembers the change history for undo, even after you close the tab)

Answer (score 4):

VS Code *View -> command palette*, run the **TypeScript: Select TypeScript version** command and **select Use Workspace version**

> or

VS Code *View -> command palette*, run the **TypeScript: Select TypeScript version** command and **select Use VS code's version**

Answer (score 2):

I used PascalCase in writing the name of component then the error disappear

Comment: This is effectively the same as what the accepted answer said.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference on my project.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to update Visual Studio and everything will work.

[CHECK HOW TO UPDATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lb7u.png)

Comment: what you're showing in that screenshot is not visual studio

Answer (score 0):

For those encountering it via VSCode:

It might sound silly, but have you tried closing out of VSCode and then reopening the project? Or deleting node_modules, installing them again, and then reopening VSCode?

I've encountered this problem where it appears stuck in said error state, but one of these usually clears it. Perhaps there's a more thoughtful approach, but the ole IT fix works often enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the `h1` tag. The problem started after removing default import statements.

Below commands fixed the issue.

```bash
rm node_modules
```

and

```bash
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

change the "moduleResolution": "Node" in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error comes up for an entirely different reason. For example I had a component defined as follows:

```
export type GaleryItem = {
  src: string;
  caption: string;
}

export default function GalleryDisplay({data}:{data:GaleryItem[]}) {
 ...
}
```

I was calling it like this:

```
var items: GalleryItem[];
// Assign items here

return (... <GaleryDisplay data={items}/> ...)
```

At any rate I got the error  Property 'data' does not exist on type "IntrinsicAttributes". Turns out all it was was a missing import. After adding

```
import {GalleryItem, GalleryDisplay} from "my/components/gallerydisplay"
```

The issue was resolved.  Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.  And sometimes the errors react throws out are quite misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In my case restarting Visual Studio Code solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the IDE (VS Code). Then the error is gone.`

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade code
- code --version  (to check the version)

`

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is specifically related to the item's first letter being small.

Problem:

But for those people who are facing this issue due to Creating the React project using Vite instead of CRA, then let me tell to those that Vite has issue with react-ts template and throwing errors in even ts.config.json files

Solution:

So if you want to have react-ts template then please use CRA for that instead of Vite, otherwise for simple react app creation Vite is best.

Thanks

Answer (score -4):

you just edit the name component to capitalize,
for ex:
before: `export default function jobAndIncome() {};`
after: `export default function JobAndIncome() {};`

Comment: The accepted answer said the same six years ago. This adds nothing new.