# TS Error: Property './PresentationAttributesForm' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I am creating a website that shows presentations.  When a user clicks on the “edit” button, they see a form to edit the presentation’s attributes.  I am having a hard time importing the presentation form, `PresentationAttributesForm`, into the main presentation page, because I’m getting an error that says `Property ‘./PresentationAttributesForm' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements’.`

I read this question about [a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414304/typescript-complains-property-does-not-exist-on-type-jsx-intrinsicelements-whe/37414418#37414418), and I don't think my error is caused by a capitalization mistake.  Also, I have @react/types installed, and I already deleted my node modules and re-did `npm install`.  I have my source code below.

`PresentationAttributes.tsx`

```
import axios from "axios";
import { isNil } from "lodash";
import * as React from "react";
import { Col } from "reactstrap";
import { Presentation, Recording } from "../../lib/Presentation";
import { getAuthRequestHeader } from "../../services/Auth";
import PresentationAttributesForm from "../PresentationAttributesForm";
import PresentationAttributesInfo from "../PresentationAttributesInfo";
import PresentationMetadataItem from "../PresentationMetadataItem";
import PresentationRecording from "../PresentationRecording";
import "./PresentationAttributes.css";
import PresentationAttributesProps from "./PresentationAttributesProps";
import PresentationAttributesState from "./PresentationAttributesState";

// tslint:disable:cyclomatic-complexity
class PresentationAttributes extends React.Component<PresentationAttributesProps, PresentationAttributesState> {
    public state: PresentationAttributesState = {
        displayForm: false,
    };

    public toggleFormDisplay = () => {
        this.setState(previousState => ({
            displayForm: !previousState.displayForm,
        }));
        // tslint:disable-next-line:semicolon
    };

    public render() {
        const { displayForm } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="Presentation-attributes-main-container">
                <Col sm={9}>
                    {displayForm ? (
                        <PresentationAttributesForm {...this.props.presentation} />
                    ) : (
                        <PresentationAttributesInfo {...this.props.presentation} />
                    )}
                </Col>
                <Col sm={3}>
                    <div className="Presentation-attributes-buttons-container">
                        <button onClick={() => this.toggleFormDisplay()}>Edit Presentation</button>
                        <div className="Presentation-attributes-vimeo-section">
                            {isNil(this.props.Presentation.vimeo_link) ? (
                                <button onClick={() => this.uploadVideo(this.props.Presentation.id)}>
                                    UPLOAD
                                </button>
                            ) : (
                                <a href={this.props.Presentation.vimeo_link}> Vimeo link </a>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PresentationAttributes;
```

`PresentationAttributesProps.tsx`

```
import { Presentation } from "../../lib/Presentation";

export default interface PresentationAttributesProps {
    meeting: Presentation;
}
```

`PresentationAttributesState.tsx`

```
export default interface PresentationAttributesState {
    displayForm: boolean;
}
```

`PresentationAttributesForm.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Presentation } from "../../lib/Presentation";

export class PresentationAttributesForm extends React.Component<{}, Presentation> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label>Presentation Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="presentationTitle" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />;
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PresentationAttributesForm;
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `reactstrap`'s `<Col/>` element expecting an intrinsic element, but you're giving it a custom one as a direct child. Have a look at the "Intrinsic elements" section on this page in TS docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html - you can also see an example of people facing/fixing this issue on this Github TS thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15449