# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry' (Polymer 2.0)

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x, custom-element

I'm facing this issue while running **polymer init** on polymer-cli.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry'

Comment: can you post a bit more info? some code?

Comment: @navnit-kapadiya: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include a [MCVE]

Comment: Please use correct English in the question. It is quite confusing. Although I've answered your question, I still suggest you to improve your question for people to understand.

Comment: see answer for the same error at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696496/965666

Answer (score 16):

Possible reasons:
- Element name starts with **uppercase alphabet**
- Element name **does not have a hyphen in it** (Thanks to **[Margherita Lazzarini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8137068/margherita-lazzarini)**)

**Long story:**
I was working with polymer CLI and when I ran **polymer init**, among the series of options it asks me, one of them was **Main element name** for which I entered **Polymer-test-element**.

It was giving me this error :
**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "Polymer-test-element" is not a valid custom element name**

The problem was I had used an **uppercase alphabet** in the declared element name. So when I replaced 'P' with 'p' it resolved the issue.

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 14):

Probably you have defined a Custom Element without a hypen (`-`) in its name.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22545622/8137068)

Answer (score -1):

Check your import, maybe you imported an element with e.g.

`<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-icons/av-icons.html">`

instead of

`<link rel="import" href="../iron-icons/av-icons.html">`

which could both be a valid path but the first one got me the DOMException.