# Detect if dom element is custom web component or html element

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

In the given html, how can I tell that a dom element is a standard html component defined by the browser or a web component defined in a script (by an author):

```
<div></div>
<custom-web-component></custom-web-component>
```

I know that there is no way to check programmatically if a web component was already registered. Also they are both considered `HTMLElement`. Is there a way to check that a dom node is standard html or custom web component? Let's asume I get the dom element using `querySelector()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element)'s name is **required** to contain a `-`, whereas an HTML-defined element will not. So:

```
if (theElement.tagName.includes("-")) {
    // It's custom
} else {
    // It isn't
}
```

(Or `.indexOf("-") != -1` for older browsers that don't have `String#includes` yet.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I've been doing some follow-up reading and I learned that there are a few [SVG elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22545622/1903781) that break the rule. It's easy to check for this scenario.

Answer (score 17):

To detect if a DOM element is a registred Custom Element, you should use `customElements.get()`.

If the element is not yet registered or if it's a standard HTML element, the method will return `undefined`.

If it's a registered Custom Element it will return its `class`.

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {} )

console.log( customElements.get( 'custom-element' ) )
console.log( customElements.get( 'p' ) )
console.log( customElements.get( 'fake-element' ) )
console.log( customElements.get( 'font-face' ) )
```

```html
<custom-element></custom-element>
<fake-element></fake-element>
<p></p>
<font-face></font-face>
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Really useful!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider that there are custom tag names that may not be defined custom elements. e.g. `document.createElement('custom-tagname')`.

If you want to check that it's actually an instance of a registered custom-element you can use `instanceof`:

```
function isDefinedCustomElement(node) {
    if (node.tagName.includes("-")) {
        return false;
    }
    const customElementClass = window.customElements.get(node.tagName.toLowerCase());
    return customElementClass && node instanceof customElementClass;
}
```