# Check for web component support

Tags: javascript

I'd like to test the browser support of web components. Thus I thought of doing it using:

`if('define' in customElements) return true;`

Is there a better or different way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this for better approach.

```
if (window.customElements) {
  // Custom elements are supported
  return true;
} else {
  // Custom elements are not supported
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can be changed to one liner to `!!window.customElements`.

Comment: Yes I agree. This is more optimised approach. I did it like this to have two different blocks if they want to have different blocks for both events. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe this: [Detect if dom element is custom web component or html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737652/detect-if-dom-element-is-custom-web-component-or-html-element)
2. in most cases only web component will have shadow dom, might also be an option