# Use el for a vue.js component that is repeated many times

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component called `Card.vue` that is duplicated many times. So there is not one instance of the component. Should I still be using `el` to link the element with the component? Ie should I be doing the following or something else?

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  el: '.card', // should I use another property (list?) or something else?
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

Comment: It seems that you're writing a single file component (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), then you shouldn't be providing any `el`.

Comment: What Thomas said, and you should only need `el` at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`el` is used for a top-level Vue instance to indicate where the instance should be inserted.

You should not generally be providing an `el` to components. They are typically inserted using custom tags within a parent's template. See [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) for some examples as well as general information.

A parent object using your component might have code like

```
<Card></Card>
```

to insert the component. Although you should really use a [safe custom tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22545622/392102) (primarily meaning it should have a hyphen) for your component.

Comment: thanks, I need to call a js function on each card (each is a mini slider/carousel). So I need to call `$('.card').flickity()`. How would either the card component or the parent component call that function?

Comment: `this.$el.flickity()`