# Mock with jest causes warnings: correct casing, tag is unrecognized and unknown properties

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have `AccountSelection`, that renders `AccountSelectionModal`.

I want to do `mount` in order to test some aspects of the user interaction:

`const wrapper = mount(<AccountSelection {...accountSelectionComponentParams} />);`

However I would like to mock `AccountSelectionModal` - I don't need it (and it is also connected component and I don't want to use store in my tests).

When I mock it with `jest.mock('../AccountSelectionModal', () => 'AccountSelectionModal');`

I start to get plenty of warnings:

```
Warning: <AccountSelectionModal /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
    console.error node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:33
```

and

```
Warning: The tag <AccountSelectionModal> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

or

```
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onHide`. It will be ignored.
```

or

```
React does not recognize the `selectedAccountId` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as
a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `selectedaccountid` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

All warnings come from props that are set on `AccountSelectionModal`.

How can I mock properly `AccountSelectionModal`

Answer (score 6):

The second argument that you pass to `mock` is a **function** that returns whatever you want it to return, and since you want to mock a component, then this function should return a **valid** react component (now it's returning a String).

This is how you should mock your component.

```
jest.mock('../AccountSelectionModal', () => () => 'AccountSelectionModal');
```

(Notice how the function passed to `mock` is now returning a function)

You can also return an String but it should be in lowercase (that [contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545621/do-custom-elements-require-a-dash-in-their-name) a dash), that way it would be considered as a custom element and not as a react element.

```
 jest.mock('../AccountSelectionModal', () => 'account-selection-modal');
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, in my snapshots I get a component named `Component`. 

    `-   <AccountSelectionModal` removed, 
    `+   <Component` added.


Is there a way to mock and preserve components name?