# Can I prevent the browser from changing <image> tags to <img />?

Tags: html

An annoying problem has come up where the browser is changing any `<image></image>` tags to `<img />`

Example to try in Microsoft's Edge browser

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <!--This is an img element-->
    <img />

    <!--This is an image element-->
    <image></image>
    </body>
</html>
```

I do not want this tag to be altered. Can anyone provide any guidance on how to prevent this from happening?

(tested using version Microsoft Edge version 42.17134.1.0)

Comment: What do you mean by altered? Where does it alter anything and how does it have an impact in your case?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you'll be able to do this. The browser is fixing what it thinks is a mistake. What do you want to use `<image>` for if not the thing that `<img>` exists for? Why do you want to have images that are not replaced content?

Comment: 1. Microsoft's Edge browser is changing any <image></image> tags to <img />
2. I have an img tag inside an <image> tag. Because the <image> tag is being changed to an img tag it's rendering improperly.

Comment: @TylerH This is an angular component. The solution I already have is to rename the component to something other than "image".

Comment: Does it still change it if it's nested inside an `<svg>` tag?  As far as I know that's the only allowed usage.

Comment: If this is angular related please update the tags on your question

Comment: @tmutton Why don't you use the `<picture>` element which is already intended to contain one `<img>` element and zero or more sources? I'm not familiar with angular, unfortunately.

Comment: @j08691 it's not angular related. It's reproducible with pure html as per my question.

Comment: But there is no `<image>` element in HTML so the browser is trying to fix the error. BTW, Chrome does the same thing.

Comment: If I am following what you are doing, then it sounds like `<image>` is a custom element. If that is the case, the name you have selected is invalid because custom element names require a dash (to avoid the sort of problem you are experiencing among others). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545621/do-custom-elements-require-a-dash-in-their-name

Comment: You cannot have `<image>` tags.

Comment: @j08691 Chrome is not renaming the element tag

Comment: @tmutton It certainly is https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a5q64x9v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use custom elements? You could refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) in MDN.

As mentioned in the article: *Note that custom element names **require a dash** to be used in them; they **can't be single words**.* You could try to use other words with a dash in them.

Comment: Referring to the link you posted

"A DOMString representing the name you are giving to the element. Note that custom element names require a dash to be used in them; they can't be single words."

I included a dash in the tag name and it worked. But I think this is more to do with the fact that the tag is no longer called "image" which Edge saw as a mistake and was changing it to "img".

Marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a tag called `<image></image>` exist which is supported by browser