# For loop doesn't iterate all elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project that I am doing for a class involving making custom HTML tags using JavaScript. I have a for loop to loop over every time the tag is used. When I run the code, it only loops over every odd tag. I am trying to make an alert tag in html.

```js
for (i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("alert").length; i++) {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("alert")[i].innerHTML);
  document.querySelectorAll("alert")[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<body>
  <alert>Hello!</alert>
  <alert>How do you do?</alert>
  <alert>Are you doing good?</alert>
  <alert>I hope you are!</alert>
  <alert>Bizzle</alert>
  <alert>Fizzle</alert>
  <alert>Grizzle</alert>
</body>
```

Comment: You are making your list shorter by one in every iteration. Btw, please declare your variables.

Comment: `<alert>` is not a valid Custom HTML element: Custom elements must have a dash in their names: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545621/do-custom-elements-require-a-dash-in-their-name

Answer (score 6):

### Problem

You are making your list shorter in every iteration

### Solution

Declare your list before the loop

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("alert")
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  alert(items[i].innerHTML);
  items[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<alert>Hello!</alert>
<alert>How do you do?</alert>
<alert>Are you doing good?</alert>
<alert>I hope you are!</alert>
<alert>Bizzle</alert>
<alert>Fizzle</alert>
<alert>Grizzle</alert>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just thought about it and I am removing the element causing the for loop to go to the next one instead of the one before it. Edit: I used a while loop to check if there was a value in the node list instead of the for loop.